# How can I get better quality for exported raster in Arcgis Pro?

Tags: layout, export, raster, arcgis

I'm trying to export some raster data I have created into an .svg file format and the end result turns out blurry for all raster layers. Boundaries for feature layers are crisp. I have this in the Layout:

[image]

and end up having this after the export:

[image]

I use the export layout menu and have applied the following settings:

[image]

I prefer using svg because I am using it in a word doc that will after be turned into a pdf. I have found that SVG is the format that lesse loses image quality when exporting the word to pdf.

Even the world topographic map baselayer is having issues and presents as blurry.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to have better quality when exporting my data?

Comment: I would recommend to convert raster to polygons prior to export the file. This output looks like a compressed image, so converting the pixels to polygons will do the trick. Be aware that is a memory expensive process

Comment: Such a simple solution and yet it hadn't occurred to me. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get (minimally) satisfactory results by saving as SVG at 96DPI (??who knew??), uploading to word doc and when exporting to pdf, I use adobe acrobat software (free trial license). This is the only one I tried that gave me somewhat quality. However, this causes a future problem of when I can't access the software anymore... And of course, the final pdf file is huge. I have to compress the file. Still don't have a final doc, but preliminary results don't distort the images very much. I guess this will be a problem for "future me"...
Still I will try to experiment with the suggestion given by @aldo_tapia to convert raster to polygons and exporting afterwards.